# Rego object.get with multileve key

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

is there any way to use object.get with multiple level key..?

My input looks like this:
`{
    "pipelineParameters" : {
        "k8" : {
            "NODES" : "1"
        },
        "ec2": {
           "NODES" : "0"
        }
}`

my data looks like 
`{
       "key": "pipelineParameters.k8.NODES"
}`

How can I get value from input based on multilevel key

Sample code

https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/iR15XnMctP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `object.get` function does not support multi-level keys. You could use the [`walk`](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#graphs) function for this if you represent the key as an array:

```
input = {
    "pipelineParameters" : {
        "k8" : {
            "NODES" : "1"
        },
        "ec2": {
           "NODES" : "0"
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

```
> walk(input, [["pipelineParameters", "k8", "NODES"], "1"])
true
> walk(input, [["pipelineParameters", "k8",  "NODES"], x])
+-----+
|  x  |
+-----+
| "1" |
+-----+
> walk(input, [["pipelineParameters", y,  "NODES"], x])
+-----+-------+
|  x  |   y   |
+-----+-------+
| "1" | "k8"  |
| "0" | "ec2" |
+-----+-------+
```

To convert your key into array you could simply write:

```
split(key, ".")
```

For example:

```
split("pipelineParameters.k8.NODES", ".")
[
  "pipelineParameters",
  "k8",
  "NODES"
]
```

Putting it all together:

```
> walk(input, [split("pipelineParameters.k8.NODES", "."), x])
+-----+
|  x  |
+-----+
| "1" |
+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not check 18.0 documentation. It worked for me